# making an input field for credit cards

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I want to create a credit card input field/s where there are 4 fields. The first 3 fields have character limits of 4, then the last one has 5 (due to Amex having an extra number).

The functionality I am trying to create will mean that when the character limit has reached its limit, it will tab to the next field.

I assume this is done easiest through Jquery. I imagine the logic could work something like:

if the field value==limit, then focus to the next field. Would that be the way to do it? Or is there a much better way?

Comment: You may find this useful: http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/

Answer (score 2):

Give them all `class="ccInput"` and then using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.ccInput').not(':last').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length == Number($(this).attr('maxlength')))
            $(this).next('.ccInput').focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that was kind of where I was headed, was just wondering if there was a better way. But thanks, that's great.

Comment: Also for the last field, I don't want that to tab, how can I stop that? Should I just make it a different class?

Comment: nope. will edit in a sec

Comment: Added `.not(':last')`. this should do the trick.